How to access the sub tables of a junction table in EF Core?
I have this method here that retrieves all the Rewards by UserId from the UserReward table:
public async Task<IList<Reward>> GetAllRewardsByUserIdAsync(Guid userId)
{
    var userRewards = await context.UserReward
        .Include(d => d.User)
        .Include(d => d.Reward)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId)
        .ToListAsync();

    IList<Reward> rewards = new List<Reward>();

    foreach (Reward reward in userRewards)
    {
        rewards.Add(reward);
    }

    return rewards;
}

And of course I get the error Can't convert UserReward into Reward but how should I go about it ?
Here are the ApplicationUser table, the Reward table and the UserReward table:
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
    
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IList<Reward> Rewards { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class Reward
{
    public Guid RewardId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasBeenUsed { get; set; }
    public IList<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiresOn { get; set; }
}

public class UserReward
{
    public Guid ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public Guid RewardId { get; set; }
    public Reward Reward { get; set; }
}


FYI You can add more navigation properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-navigations-to-join-entity. Then context.Reward.Where(r => r.UserRewards.Any(u => u.ApplicationUserId == userId)). Or you can query what you actually need. context.Reward.Where(r => r.Users.Any(u => u.Id == userId)).

Thank you, is .Any() a performant query ? Could it affect performances ?

And also would that remove the need for the junction table ? @JeremyLakeman

Query is simple when you use Select:
public async Task<IList<Reward>> GetAllRewardsByUserIdAsync(Guid userId)
{
    var rewards = await context.UserReward
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId)
        .Select(d => d.Reward)
        .ToListAsync();

    return rewards;
}

Also you can start your query from ApplicationUser
public async Task<IList<Reward>> GetAllRewardsByUserIdAsync(Guid userId)
{
    var rewards = await context.ApplicationUser
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == userId)
        .SelectMany(u => u.Rewards)
        .ToListAsync();

    return rewards;
}

